# What is a proper way to get aggregate columns in queries using GreenDao?

Tags: android, aggregate-functions, greendao

GreenDao and ORMs in general makes us gain a lot on development time and mainainability versus using raw queries.

But I feel like I am running in a case where an ORM, especially GreenDao, is limited versus performing a raw query:

Let A and B be two entities; A and B have a one-to-many relationship; A is the "one" side and B the "many" side.
I need to retrieve a list of A entities and for each one get the number of linked B entities that match certain criteria.

A real-world example would be a messaging app that displays a list of threads comprising several messages; beside each thread the number of unread messages (or total messages if no condition) would be shown.

Using raw SQL this is easy; I would get the aggregate column using a `COUNT` statement and that's it. The downside is the need to manually parse the results and build the list of entities; and we lose the benefit of lazy loading using GreenDao-provided `LazyList`.

Another solution would be to call `queryRawCreate()` on the A entity; the problem is that the generated A entity needs to have a member variable not directly linked to a database column, and get GreenDao to map the aggregate column into this member variable. I wonder if the current version supports this feature.

Should I go for the full raw SQL solution or can I leverage GreenDao, even partially, to automatically return a list of entities that include the aggregate columns ?